# Is it common convention to use a pixels-to-rem function for all size values in React (with styled-components)?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

We inherited some react projects that use styled components.

Everything is mostly “normal” as react/styled docs would exemplify, but everywhere we specify sizes in the styled components (fonts, margins, etc) there is a function called pxToRem used like so:

```
font-size: pxToRem(16)
width : pxToRem(400)
```

I’m under the impression that using this everywhere is kind of wonky, and that for fonts we can just use the commonly known mapping (like 14px = .875rem) and specify that rem value (presuming the css reset is there). For container widths, we can either use pixels for containers that should not change size, or use padding/margin to allow containers to grow to fit their font.

That conversion utility is of course useful in multiple situations to avoid statically computing a rem value, so it’s surely not an anti-pattern itself, but I suggested that in my experience, I don’t usually see that conversion used for every size value. It feels like code smell, but the team is under the impression that most people likely use a similar pattern.

Just seeking resolution of the commonality of this pattern, and responses on a normal level of usage for such a utility.

Answer (score 2):

This is how Facebook does it (they posted May 8, 2020):

> "By using rems, we can respect user-specified defaults and are able to
> provide controls for customizing font size without requiring changes
> to the stylesheet. Designs, however, are usually created using CSS
> pixel values. Manually converting to rems adds engineering overhead
> and the potential for bugs, so we have our build tool do this
> conversion for us."

Source:
https://engineering.fb.com/2020/05/08/web/facebook-redesign/

Extra explanations by Frank Yan & Ashley Watkins:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxPtYJRjLL0

Answer (score 1):

There are no conventions in development unless you enforce them in your project.

If you look into the [styled-components documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles), they use a mixture of px, rem and em but no pxToRem function.

It seems the developer who wrote that old project is used to working with pixel. Then a requirement came along "The user base uses different devices with different pixel densities". Easy fix: pxToRem function "solves" this requirement.

> That conversion utility is of course useful in multiple situations to
>   avoid statically computing a rem value, so it’s surely not an
>   anti-pattern itself, but I suggested that in my experience at other
>   companies, you don’t usually see that conversion used for every size
>   value. It feels like code smell, but the team is under the impression
>   that most people must be using a similar pattern.

I find it astonishing the your team assumes this must be the norm without looking into the styled-components documentation. It's your project now. Treat it like your other projects.

Use the convention you used in your past projects.

XOR

Use the convention from the styled-components documentation.